# ELK Stack using Tweepy and zmq - Cant get it working

Tags: python-2.7, logstash, zeromq, tweepy, elastic-stack

Help, I am trying to create an Elk Stack using tweepy and zmq in python and outputing the tweets in json to logstash. I am supposed to end up with 4 Terminal at the end:

```
T1 - tweepy_stream.py
T2 - zmq_json.py | logstash -f twitter_logstash.config
T3 - Elastic Search
T4 - Kibana
```

the issue I am having is somewhere between tweepy and the logstash config. The tweepy script outputs tweets but im not sure if the zmq ive set up is working or if the config file is wrong:

here is the code for tweepy_stream.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

import zmq
import time

# Went to http://apps.twitter.com and create an app.
# The consumer key and secret is generated after you create the app
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""

# After the step above, you will be redirected to the app's page.
# Create an access token under "Your access token" section
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
   """ A listener handles tweets that are received from the stream.
   This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
   """
   def on_data(self, data):
       print (data)
       return True

   def on_error(self, status):
       print(status)

if __name__=='__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['vegas'])
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:4321")

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    socket.send("stream %d" % stream)
    print ("Sent: %d:" % stream)
```

The zmq sub to json output "this is my tweepy_json.py
    #imports json and zmq libraries
    import json
    import zmq

```
#connects SUB socket to tcp://127.0.0.1:4321
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "stream")
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4321")

#Takes the subscribed tweets and formats them in json
while True:
    stream = socket.recv()
    print("Received:", stream)
    tweet_msg = " ".join(socket.recv().split()[1:])
    tweet     = json.loads(tweet_msg)

    if "user" in tweet and "text" in tweet:
        output_tweet          = tweet["user"]
        output_tweet["the_tweet"] = tweet["text"]

        print(json.dumps(output_tweet))
```

then in the terminal I have this to run the zmq sub and pass the json output to logstash

```
tweepy_json.py' | ./logstash -f twitter_logstash.config
```

finally this is the twitter_logstash.config I am trying to use

```
#stdin_to_stdout.rb _to_elasticsearch.rb
input{ 
    stdin{
        codec => "json_lines"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
    stdout {
        codec => "dots"
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the output of `zmq_json.py`?

Comment: Sorry edit mistake zmq_json.py is tweepy_json.py. When I run it in he terminal it just sit there waiting for tweets

Comment: From what I can understand, I don't think the problem is with the logstash config. And I can't help you with zeromq.

Answer (score 0):

### To isolate the root cause validate this on ZeroMQ part:

about a two minutes lasting `sleep()`-y sender part:

```
context = zmq.Context()

socket  = context.socket( zmq.PUB )
socket.bind(             "tcp://127.0.0.1:4321" )
socket.setsockopt(        zmq.LINGER, 0 )

aSUB_TopicFILTER = "stream"

for aLoopNUM in range( 120 ):
    time.sleep(1)
    socket.send( "a plain text to be delivered on Access Point w/o TopicFILTER" )
    aRawPAYLOAD = "{0:} {1:}. PUB/d MESSAGE".format( aSUB_TopicFILTER,
                                                     aLoopNUM
                                                     )
    socket.send(                             aRawPAYLOAD )
    print(       "Sent:  [[[{0:}]]]".format( aRawPAYLOAD ) )


socket.close()
context.term()
```

against a listener:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket  = context.socket( zmq.SUB )
socket.connect(          "tcp://127.0.0.1:4321" )
socket.setsockopt(        zmq.LINGER, 0 )
socket.setsockopt(        zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "stream" )

socALL  = context.socket( zmq.SUB )
socALL.connect(          "tcp://127.0.0.1:4321" )
socALL.setsockopt(        zmq.LINGER, 0 )
socALL.setsockopt(        zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )

try:
    for aLoopNUM in range( 1200 ):
        aMsgF = socket.recv( zmq.NOBLOCK )
        aMsgV = socALL.recv( zmq.NOBLOCK )
        if (   aMsgV == ""
           and aMsgF == "" ):
             time.sleep( 0.25 )
             continue
        print( aLoopNUM, "FILTER'd:[[[{0:}]]]".format( repr( aMsgF ) ) )
        print( aLoopNUM, "plain:   [[[{0:}]]]".format( repr( aMsgV ) ) )

except KeyboardInterrupt:
     pass
finally:
     socket.close()
     socALL.close()
     context.term()
```

Given this trivial validator test shows the appropriately ordered messages being delivered and displayed correctly working filtering, the problem is not in ZeroMQ.